# How to just show the Outlook web Addin name when mouse hovers over the button

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

When hover mouse over our Outlook web-addin button, it always display "[AddinName] - [ButtonLabel]".

Is there a way to just display one of them rather than both. Like just "[AddinName]" or [ButtonLabel]?

Have been reading documents on [Office Dev Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins), but could not find anything related. Need some help on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something you will be able to control. The behavior you observe comes from particular application implementation.

- For Office 365 online the mouse hover displays the name of the add-in
  and the button label ...

  [image]
- For Desktop Outlook the tip displays button label and button tip ...

  [image]